# Parameters For Defining the performance of Api Using Load Testing

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I am performing Load Testing on api using Jmeter. I am able to generate aggregate report for that now I am trying to analyse the report through the values of different columns .SO like I have average time now on what bases can I say that my average time is good or bad Is there any specified range for these values

Is there any predefined standards for values of the aggregate report that this should be my range for the a good performance

Answer (score 0):

There are no any pre-defined standards, you either need to ask around whether there are any [NFR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement) or [SLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-level_agreement) associated with the API endpoints. If your project doesn't have any your API consumers might have some.

If there are no any requirements you can suggest running a [stress test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Stress_testing): start with 1 virtual user and gradually increase the load until response time starts growing or errors start occurring. This way you will be able to get the [saturation point](http://hd-performance.blogspot.com/2010/05/saturation-point.html) and report it as the result of your testing activitites.

More information: [3 Things to Look Out for When Stress Testing API](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/stress-testing-api)